# Too big bottom shadow and too little top one ? I need them equal

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIGBv.png)

Hi I took a screenshot of my Android device, my idea is to make all shadows from the cardView appear equal size and now it seems that the top is too little and the bottom is too big. If anybody knows how to achieve this please comment and give advice.

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_weight="0.91"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        card_view:contentPadding="-8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_shape"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/lift_on_touch"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">
```

Comment: I tried removing  card_view:contentPadding="-8dp" . Looks like does not matter.

Comment: shadows are pre-defined you will need to make your own card backgound if you want something different

Comment: DO you know how to do that?

Comment: Use photoshop and create your own background to use

Answer (score 0):

From the **Material design** documentation: https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/environment.html#environment-3d-world

> Key lights create directional shadows, while ambient light creates soft shadows from all angles.

In other words, system default shadows will always be bigger on the bottom of the view than they are on the top. And, in fact, shadows shown below objects near the bottom of the screen will be larger than shadows shown below objects near the top of the screen.

If you require equal shadows around all sides of your view, you will have to create a fake shadow by hand.